# "error module dav_svn does not exist"

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, ubuntu-9.10

I accidentally deleted the mod_svn on my webserver, and now I am stuck. Everything I try to do anything with it (remove it or reinstall it with apt-get), I get that message and apt fails. I know I could reinstall Apache, but I am trying to avoid that at all costs (unless I can do it in such a way that would keep my config files).

Any ideas on how to deal with this?

Comment: can you give the full output from apt ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I fixed it. I had to mirror the configuration on a VM, then copy the missing files over. After that, apt let me remove the package and reinstall it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to run

```
sudo apt install libapache2-mod-svn
```

Answer (score -2):

Some kind soul posted an answer that worked for me here: 
http://kcode.de/wordpress/1734-fixing-libapache2-svn-error-module-dav_svn-does-not-exist

Comment: You should add the answer, not just a link.